# ng-Idle injector error when angular.bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, ng-idle

I'm getting an `$injector:modulerr` error

index.html  (loading the idle js at the end, after everything)

```
<script src="/lib/ng-idle/angular-idle.js"></script>
```

Angular, ngIdle

```
app = angular.module("lpApp", ['ngGrid', 'ngCookies', 'ui.sortable', 'toaster','ngIdle', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ui.date', 'ngTable']);
```

The error occurs here, for some reason ngIdle is causing a problem when trying to bootstrap.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
angular.bootstrap(document, ['lpApp']);
});
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove ngIdle as a dependency?

Comment: No, it did not work. I am moving to another solution. Thanks.